# Completeness of D3 functionality by use with Python connectors

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, d3.js

There are some bridges available that enable using D3 from Python. I need the graphical power from D3 but I absolutely dislike that JavaScript/React verbatim where every COMMAND looks like `<ANNOY angry="yes">COMMAND</ANNOY>` That's why I prefered to stay with Python for the core and GUI instead of some from the JS world.
Target is some MindMapping comparable thing. So I need e.g. context menu capabilities on graphical elements. I tried something like this with Matplotlib - but it feels like misuse to force these charts to such user interactions like context menu provision, drag & drop etc.

So in a nutshell: does at least one of these D3 bridges/connectors really provide the full functionality of D3 to Python (... like the D3 Context Menu library ...) or is the available set restricted to some manually adapted modules?

I found things like D3blocks but could not find, if this is a gateway (so everything that is in D3 would be accessible) or if it is a port (so only ported subsets can be there).

Comment: What have you actually tried and evaluated of the D3 wrappers?  You ask the question, you "I found things like D3blocks", but I don't read that you actually tried and got something working.  Read the following links, try the packages and report back with your evaluations.  Thank you.
https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-beautiful-stand-alone-interactive-d3-charts-with-python-804117cb95a7  or 

https://erdogant.github.io/d3graph/pages/html/Abstract.html or 

https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/index.html